# Dirichlet triangle mesh

Tags: harmonic-analysis, dirichlet-series, harmonic-numbers

I was reading up on the Dirichlet problem, and was truly hoping if anyone here has the time to help make me understand this a bit better. In particular, the question relates to harmonic maps. My understanding is that a A (smooth) map $\varphi\colon M\to N$ between Riemannian manifolds $M$ and $N$ is called harmonic if it is a critical point of the Dirichlet energy functional. But now, lets imagine $M$ is a triangle mesh, which is a topological disk, how can I find its harmonic map? To be more specific, suppose $f\colon M \to R^2$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta f(v_i)=0&&\forall v_i\notin\partial M\\
f(v_i)=g(v_i)&&\forall v_i\in\partial M,
\end{cases}$$
where $g\colon \partial M \to R^2$ is given.

I vaguely recall once learning about random walks, would that work here? How would that work?

Thank you all, I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format your posts. Please *especially* do not post low-resolution screenshots attempting to show mathematics, as they are extremely hard to read. I attempted to interpret what you wrote. Please verify that I did so correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should revise the problem statement; as given in the question, it says  that $\Delta f=0$ on the boundary, which is not right.

A harmonic map into $\mathbb R^2$ with Euclidean metric is just a pair of real-valued harmonic functions. To find such functions in a discrete setting, you can use the [finite element method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method). Or, if you are looking for approximation defined on vertices of the mesh, you can use the discrete Laplacian: $\Delta f(v)$ is the average of $f$ over all neighbors of $v$, minus $f(v)$. Setting the discrete Laplacian to zero at all interior points, and equating $f$ to $g$ at the boundary points, you get a large system of linear equations, which can be easily solved with existing numerical algebra routines.

There is also the iterative approach: fill the vertices with some values at first, and then update them, replacing each with the average of its neighbors.

Random walk is not a practical  way to find the solution.

Comment: I believe that what originally looked like $/\in$ was supposed to be $\notin$.

Comment: @Post NO Bills can you elaborate on the answer? I am confused